# I want to get multiple calculations like 2+2+2 in my jframe calculator

Tags: java, math, jframe, calculator

I'm making a jFrame calculator for a school project but whenever I try to calculate something like 2+2+2 I get 4. like its only calculating the last 2 digits. does anyone know how to fix this? here is my code

```
//numbers
private void NulNulActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
Display.setText(Display.getText()+NulNul.getText());
}                                      

private void NulActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                    
Display.setText(Display.getText()+Nul.getText());
}                                   

private void PuntActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
if(PointClick == 0){
Display.setText(Display.getText()+Punt.getText());    
}
else{
    Punt.enable(false);

}
PointClick = 1;
}                                    

private void EenActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                    
Display.setText(Display.getText()+Een.getText());
}                                   

private void TweeActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
Display.setText(Display.getText()+Twee.getText());
}                                    

private void DrieActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
Display.setText(Display.getText()+Drie.getText());
}                                    

private void VierActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
Display.setText(Display.getText()+Vier.getText());
}                                    

private void VijfActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
Display.setText(Display.getText()+Vijf.getText());
}                                    

private void ZesActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                    
Display.setText(Display.getText()+Zes.getText());
}                                   

private void ZevenActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
Display.setText(Display.getText()+Zeven.getText());
}                                     

private void AchtActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
Display.setText(Display.getText()+Acht.getText());
}                                    

private void NegenActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
Display.setText(Display.getText()+Negen.getText());
}                                     

//Clear
private void ClearActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
Display.setText("");
PointClick = 0;
}                                     

//Back
private void BackActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
String text;
text = Display.getText();
int len = text.length();
text = text.substring(0, len-1);
Display.setText(text);
}                                    

private void PlusActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
firstnumber = Double.parseDouble(Display.getText());
Display.setText("");
PlusClick= 1;
MinusClick = MultiplyClick = DivideClick = PercentClick = PowerClick = PointClick = 0;
}                                    

private void EqualsActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
secondnumber = Double.parseDouble(Display.getText());
if(PlusClick > 0){
    Result = firstnumber + secondnumber;
    Display.setText(String.valueOf(Result));
}
else if(MinusClick > 0){
    Result = firstnumber - secondnumber;
Display.setText(String.valueOf(Result));
}
else if(MultiplyClick > 0){
    Result = firstnumber * secondnumber;
Display.setText(String.valueOf(Result));
}
else if(DivideClick > 0){
    Result = firstnumber / secondnumber;
Display.setText(String.valueOf(Result));
}
else if(PowerClick > 0){
    for(int i=1;i<=secondnumber;i++)
    {
        Result = Result * firstnumber;
    } 
Display.setText(String.valueOf(Result));    
}
else if(PercentClick > 0){
    Result = (firstnumber * secondnumber) / 100;
Display.setText(String.valueOf(Result));    
}
}                                      

private void MinActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                    
firstnumber = Double.parseDouble(Display.getText());
Display.setText("");
MinusClick= 1;
PlusClick = MultiplyClick = DivideClick = PercentClick = PowerClick = PointClick = 0;
}                                   

private void KeerActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
firstnumber = Double.parseDouble(Display.getText());
Display.setText("");
MultiplyClick= 1;
MinusClick = PlusClick = DivideClick = PercentClick = PowerClick = PointClick = 0;
}                                    

private void DelenActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
firstnumber = Double.parseDouble(Display.getText());
Display.setText("");
DivideClick= 1;
MinusClick = MultiplyClick = PlusClick = PercentClick = PowerClick = PointClick = 0;
}                                     

private void WortelActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
firstnumber = Double.parseDouble(Display.getText());
Display.setText(String.valueOf(Math.sqrt(firstnumber)));
}                                      

private void PIActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                   
Display.setText(String.valueOf(Math.PI));
}                                  

private void MachtActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
firstnumber = Double.parseDouble(Display.getText());
Display.setText("");
PowerClick= 1;
MinusClick = MultiplyClick = PlusClick = PercentClick = DivideClick = PointClick = 0;
}                                     

private void ProcentActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
firstnumber = Double.parseDouble(Display.getText());
Display.setText("");
PercentClick= 1;
MinusClick = MultiplyClick = PlusClick = PowerClick = DivideClick = PointClick = 0;
}                                       

private void InverseActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
firstnumber = Double.parseDouble(Display.getText());
Display.setText(String.valueOf(1 / firstnumber));
}                                       

private void PlusminusActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
firstnumber = Double.parseDouble(Display.getText());
Display.setText(String.valueOf((-1) * firstnumber));
}
```

Comment: You only have `firstnumber` and `secondnumber`, so it only adds two numbers. What exactly did you try, to make it work with more than two numbers?

Comment: Please learn to indent your code to show the structure of your program!

Comment: Well the point is, this is kinda my First day java, and I dont really like it so....

Answer (score 1):

It indeed does calculate only 2 last digits, because you don't store any of the previous ones. Let's make your example 2+3+4 for clarity. Your steps are:

1. Read 2
2. Read +, store 2 as `firstnumber`
3. Read 3
4. Read +, store 3 as `firstnumber` (overriding our previous value)
5. Read 4
6. Read =, store 4 as `secondnumber`, calculate `firstnumber` + `secondnumber`

What you should do, using your approach, is calculating 'subresult' in step 4 (and in the next steps if needed) and storing it in `firstnumber` variable.

Comment: I know what you are thinking but I have No clue hoe to edit that into my code, I got everything just from a lot of tutorials.

Comment: @Benjamin You have to store two informations: (a) is it first operation? if no - calculate (b) what was the last operation? Then check it on every non digit input. Note that you can use the exact same method to calculate in every action (including `equalsAction`). So you can start with what you've got in `equalsActionPerformed` method. It is pretty close to what it should look like. Extract it to external method and try to use in every step.